# Smoothness of averaged forms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms

Spivak's book "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Volume 5" says the following on page 309 (I'll simplify here a bit):
Let $G$ be a compact, connected Lie Group and $a \mapsto \eta(a)$ a smooth family of $k$-forms on $G$, where $\eta(a)$ is defined for all $a$ in an open subset $U \subset G$. I think with smooth family he means that
$$ a \mapsto \eta(a)_p(X_1(p),\dots,X_k(p))$$
is a smooth function for any $p$ and $X_i$'s on $U$.
Then he says we can form the following integral:
$$ \int_U \eta(a) \,da = \int_U (a \mapsto \eta(a)_p(X_1(p),\dots,X_k(p)))\, da ,$$
which is again a $k$-form **on $G$**.

If $U = G$ one can prove that this is a $k$-form by applying the dominated convergence theorem and checking that this is a smooth function on a neighborhood of $p$. But how do I do the case where $U$ is a proper open subset? I don't see why the integral exists - why does this function not blow up if you approach the boundary of $U$?

Comment: It's slightly odd to say "$a \mapsto \eta(a)$ a smooth family of $k$-forms on $G$, where $\eta(a)$ is defined for all $a$ in an open subset $U \subset G$": The first clause says $\eta$ is defined on all of $G$, the second (implied by the first, but not conversely) says $\eta$ is defined in $U$. If the first is true, then $\eta$ can't blow up at the boundary of $U$ because $\eta$ is defined in all of $G$. Are you sure that's not what Spivak means?

Comment: Thanks for you comment! As far as I understand he means that $\eta(a)$ for every $a \in U$ is a smooth $k$-form on $G$ by saying "smooth family of $k$-forms on $G$. The set $U$ is more or less a parametrization of this family in the following sense: $a\in U \mapsto (\eta(a)\colon p \mapsto \eta(a)_p \in \Lambda^k (T^\ast_p G)$. So I think the first clause does not say $\eta$ itself is defined on $G$, for my understanding it says $\eta(a)$ is defined on $G$. Otherwise you don't even have a family of forms, you rather have one form.

Comment: In the preceeding paragraph Spivak defines a new form by $\tilde{\omega}(X_1,\dots,X_k) = \int_G ( a \mapsto L_a^\ast \omega(X_1,\dots,X_k)) \, da$ and after that he says: "more generally, given a smooth family of $k$-forms... [continues with the above]". This $a$ does NOT evaluate this form, $L_a^\ast \omega$ is just another form, which still needs to be evaluated. Like a family of forms. I think this speaks for my point of view?

Comment: Ah, I see. I was reading the first part of the sentence as there being a mapping $G \to \Omega^{k} G$ (the space of forms on $G$), and the second as meaning the restriction of this map to $U$. Given the added context of your second comment, my reading looks _conceivable_, but not as plausible as your reading....

Comment: Eventually I think now that your reading is the one Spivak meant, but he should have made that clearer in my opinion. So I guess $a \mapsto \eta(a)$ on $U$ is just a restriction of the same map defined for all $a \in G$. Then everything works similar to the case $U = G$. Thank you for your comments, that made me think about it!